# problemas de conexión a PostgeSQL con VB

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, windows-mobile

estoy haciendo una aplicación para pda, en visual studio 2008(VB), el caso es que quiero conectarme a un servidor a través de la aplicación, y todo lo que quiero hacer una consulta a la base de datos PostgreSQL. El problema viene cuando ejecuta la aplicación desde el propio visual studio, me da error al conectarme al server (conn.Open() como se puede ver en la imagen), y me dice : Se intentó realizar una operación de socket en un host inaccesible". Pero cuando hago la conexión por consola, la consulta me retorna datos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
Try
        If Me.txtUsuario.Text = "" And Me.txtPass.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Ingresar Usuario y Contraseña")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim conn As New PgSqlConnection("Server=xxx; Port=5432; User Id=xxx; 
                                         Password=xxx; Database=xxx;")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New PgSqlCommand("select * from ivs_sysusuarios where 
                                     ivs_sysusuarios.""USUARIO""='" & 
                                     txtUsuario.Text & "' and 
                                     ivs_sysusuarios.""CONTRASENA""='" & 
                                     txtPass.Text & "'", conn)

        'conn.Open()

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If (dr.HasRows = True) Then
            MsgBox("todo bien")
        Else
            MsgBox("user y pass malos ")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Ocurrio un error, favor contactar al admin", ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Recibo un user y pass ingresados por el Usuario y los comparo con mi base de datos (un login simple)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por un lado, en [es.so] preferimos que el código sea texto y no una imagen para poder analizar éste correctamente. Por otro lado, parece un error claramente de conexión. Son todos los datos correctos? estas en un equipo diferente a servidor del PostgreSql?

Comment: podrias explicar a que te refieres con conexion por consola?

Comment: Hola Pikoh, gracias por tu consejo, editare mi pregunta y colocare el código. Los datos son todos correctos ya que como escribí en el post Ejecuto la misma conexión y consulta en una "Aplicación Consola" y esta me retorna datos pero al ejecutar el mismo código en un "PDA" tengo el error de conexión.

Comment: Hola gbuanchi, en el mismo proyecto creo una "Aplicación Consola" para probar la conexión y consulta (eso es específicamente)

Answer (score 0):

Recordando esta situación, el problema ocurría porque el Capturador Móvil no estaba conectado a internet, una vez que se conecto a través de wifi el problema fue solucionado.